# Global variables and Go

Tags: go, graphql, graphql-go

I am currently trying to work on a small Go project, and I have a problem I am trying to solve.

I'm currently using `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` to handle database operations for the backend of a GraphQL server, and I wanted to be able to store the DB connection in a global variable accessible throughout the entire project (including sub-packages).

My first attempt was at creating a variable named `db` by doing the following in my `main.go` file:

```
var db *gorm.DB
var err error
```

then inside the `init()` function:

```
func init() {
    db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "credential stuff here")
    db.AutoMigrate(&modelStructHere)
    defer db.Close()
}
```

There isn't any crashing, but I would assume due to scoping, the `db` variable is only usable inside `main.go`, but I also need to be able to use this inside `gql/gql.go`, where my GraphQL resolver is currently located.

Perhaps I should move this chunk of code (DB init) to the actual resolver file, since there's really no use for DB operations outside of such a thing anyway, so maybe that's the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move it to another package, and make it capital `var DB *gorm.DB`. Then you can import it wherever. The issue with the way you're doing it now is that `gql.go` can't import from main because that'd be a dependency cycle. Moving it to another non-main package removes the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex's comment is spot on. Create a folder named "database" and inside put a file called "database.go" containing this:

```
package database
// the imports go here
var DB *gorm.DB
```

Now you can use it wherever you like with `database.DB`. You should not make the error variable global, handle it in the same function that initializes the DB. The init function can be in any place, usually you want it at the beginning of your program in the main function.